# How to encode byte[] in proto buffs

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is there an equivalent to int8 or byte type in proto buffs? I would like to send a byte array object.

Comment: Be careful with the size the you send: "As a general rule of thumb, if you are dealing in messages **larger than a megabyte each**, it may be time to consider an alternate strategy." - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques

Answer (score 91, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar

> bytes: May contain any arbitrary sequence of bytes no longer than 2<sup>32</sup>.

Comment: Unfortunately still serializes to strings in java. But thanks for the link.

Comment: No, according to the documentation the corresponding Java type is `ByteString`. You can get the byte array itself using the `toByteArray` method.

Comment: In case you already have the byte[] array just use LiteralByteString so you don't have to copy it over.

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking to store a *single* byte, however,  I would suggest using the Int32. It is a 'variant' type variable that will change size depending on the data that is stored in it. So if you are storing a single byte, it will be the smallest structure. The byteS data type is actually quite large in comparison. This is because the bytes structure holds data such as index length and other properties.

On serialization, I noticed a size difference of about half when switching from a single byte stored in a byteS to an int32.

Note, however, that this *does not* apply to *multiple* bytes being stored in the byteS, which I suspect will be much smaller than storing individual Int32.

Answer (score 8):

The ByteString class provides methods to convert a few types to protobuff type "bytes" or ByteString

```
public static ByteString CopyFrom(params byte[] bytes);
public static ByteString CopyFrom(string text, Encoding encoding);
```