# How to store a single byte in a protocol buffer?

Tags: protocol-buffers

my java class is below,

```
public final class TraceOptions {
private final byte options;

private TraceOptions(byte options) {
    this.options = options;
}
```

What type in protobuffer 3 should I put here?

```
message TraceOptions {
  ? traceOptions = 1;
 }
```

Comment: There is no type for byte in protobuff 2 and 3.

Comment: you will have to use int32, there is no "byte".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode byte\[\] in proto buffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421050/how-to-encode-byte-in-proto-buffs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for `bytes`? It's listed under the `Scalar Value Types` [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar). It's typically used to store a variable length number of bytes, so not sure on the efficiency of using it to store a single byte.

The type `uint32` uses a variable length encoding, so that's probably the most efficient thing you can do.

If you look at how integers are encoded [in the docs here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#simple) you'll see that using an int32 is likely your best bet.

Comment: I am looking for byte, not for bytes

Comment: @zheyiyi then as noted by Prasath and Dylan you will need to use something else, there is no single byte option.

Comment: @zheyiyi updated answer, the `int*` types (except for fixedint) are variable length encoded so that is probably your best bet.